# Can you check if a static variable is loaded in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, static

I know we can use reflection to check if the class is loaded. However it would appear that although the class is loaded, the static variable I am looking at does not get loaded until I access it for the first time. The variable in question is a `WebDriver` in my `TestDriver` class.

So, my problem is that I have a test details interface to enter in some test details before the execution of the test. When I press start test on this interface, the `WebDriver` opens and the tests are performed. However, when I don't press the start test button, and close the test details interface, the `ChromeDriver` is opened first and then closed; which is unnecessary. So if there was a way to check if the driver is initialized before calling `driver.quit()`, I can call `driver.quit()` if it is initialized and not if otherwise.

Comment if you need me to clarify any details, I know I'm not great at asking questions.

```
@Override
public void dispose(){
    try{
        Method m = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("findLoadedClass", new Class[] {String.class});
        m.setAccessible(true);
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Object isclassloaded = m.invoke(cl, "testframework.TestDriver");
        //System.out.println(isclassloaded == null);
        if(isclassloaded != null){
            TestDriver.driver.quit();
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

TestDriver.java

```
public class TestDriver {

    public static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do `if (TestDriver.driver != null) then TestDriver.driver.quit()`?

Comment: Yep. By accessing the variable the driver has to open, rendering the check pointless.

Comment: So you are going to work for hours to find a way, if it's even possible, to check and see if the driver is instantiated so you don't have to do `driver.quit()`? Why? You might save a few ms when the script runs but spend hours looking for the solution.

Comment: No.. I'm not going to work for hours to find a solution. I'm working away here writing more test cases, and occasionally checking this question to see if someone more experienced than me has a solution. This issue is trivial, but I am still interested to find a solution. Don't be so quick to assume you know things.

Comment: Accessing a static variable triggers class initialization. Invoking a static method triggers class initialization. Instantiation of an instance triggers class initialization. Reflection does not necessarily trigger class initialization. Loading a class does not trigger class initialization. Checking that the class is loaded doesn't check if it's initialized. Loading and initialization are not the same thing. Just use the class and give up the reflection foolishness.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand what I'm asking here Lew. It doesn't matter anymore though because Erich gave me a solution that worked.

Comment: @LewBloch using the lazy initialization idiom the OP can do just that: arbitrarily use or not use the class, with or without accessing the `driver` instance, and finally clean up including calling `quit()` on the driver instance **if necessary**.

Comment: I've had similar tests that needed to clean up the `WebDriver` instance only if it was initialized and it was never that complicated. Maybe because I never declare the `driver` variable as `static`, so it is controllable on each test instance. I initialize the `driver` in the test setup and tear it down in the teardown, and neither of those methods is `static` either. It seems much simpler that way to me.

Comment: @LewBloch Agreed, but the OP asked how to best handle a static driver reference.

Comment: The best way to handle a static driver reference is to make it non-static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not answer the OP's question directly (or: the answer is 'no'), but provides a work around.

You can add a lazy accessor function that creates and stores the `driver` instance:

```
private static WebDriver driver;

public static WebDriver driver() {
    if (driver == null) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    return driver;
}
```

and then add a `quit()` method:

```
public static void quit() {
    if (driver != null) driver.quit();
}
```

Please note that this code is not thread safe!

Comment: Thanks! I never even thought about doing it this way before. A fresh pair of eyes is always helpful.

Comment: Since classes are lazily loaded and initialized anyway, the lazy-initialize idiom is unnecessary.